# a new dataframe from joining two dataframes throw following error when any operations is performed 'NoneType' object has no attribute

Tags: pyspark

If I run

```
spdf_SRCustomersWaddress = spdf_SRSalesCustomers.join(
  spdf_SRSalesAddress, 
  spdf_SRSalesCustomers.CustomerID == spdf_SRSalesAddress.CustomerID,
  "inner"
)
```

the resulting dataframe will not perform any operation such as show(), count(), printSchema(), etc.

Comment: Could you add a reproducible example, or at least the full error (stack trace)?

Comment: %python
spdf_SRCustomersWaddress.drop("CustomerID")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'drop'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-3093838815898509> in <module>
----> 1 spdf_SRCustomersWaddress.drop("CustomerID")

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'drop'

Comment: @ScootCork I guess my question is, is it possible to generate a df off of joining two dfs?

Comment: Yes that is definitely possible, best to add the full stack trace as an edit to your question. However this still doesn't give us enough details to answer your question. All I can tell is that `spdf_SRCustomersWaddress` is None. This can be for many reasons, could be that you're doing a .show() and saving the return value..